# Directly assign value of struct member into variable

Tags: c, function, pointers, struct, initialization

I had come across the following code which is very new and interesting.

```
u8 m_var = stptfunc()->mem;
```

Never seen these kind of initialization before. The code compiles and run fine.
I was just curious if this is a common Practice.

Usually I will code like this...

```
strtype *ptrfunc()
{
// statements
}

sttype *stvar = ptrfunc();
u8 var = stvar->mem;
```

Example code:

```
typedef unsigned char u8;

typedef struct{
    u8 mem;
}sttype;

sttype *stptfunc(void)
{
    static sttype stvar;
    stvar.mem = 255;
    return &stvar;
}

int main()
{
    u8 m_var = stptfunc()->mem;
    printf("value of %d",m_var);
    return 0;
}
```

output
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rSUaD.png

Comment: It works because `stptfunc` is returning the address of a `static` variable. In my experience this is not common practice - but it may be. I guess it depends on who you ask.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp Hi...Yes it works fine. Is this a common practice?

Comment: Never seen it done like that before, and I personally think it's pretty bad practice :)

Answer (score 0):

`stptfunc()->mem` indicates `stptfunc` is a function returning a pointer which is being dereferenced to get its `mem` field. Since we have the entire program we can see this assumption holds up.

This is probably bad practice. What if `stptfunc` returns `NULL`? There is no guarantee it won't.

In such a simple program, it's not a big deal, but it's a bad practice to get into.

Also, as per the comments, the static variable within a function is probably a very poor practice vs. using malloc/free.